# Querying database for duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to see if a zipcode already exists before I add a new one:

With an empty query, I get the answer NO
With anythin in the search fields, I get yes, even if the zipcode does not exist.

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zipcodes FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcodes='$search'");
if ($result = $search) {
$search = "yes";
}else{
$search = "no";
}
```

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: use `$result == $search` instead of `$result = $search`

Comment: off topic, but important: be aware that the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and it is strongly recommended not to use them. The PHP manual recommends using either equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library instead.

Answer (score 4):

You are using one equals sign on this line:

`if ($result = $search)`

Which is assigning `$result` to `$search` instead of comparing equality, and then always returning true. Use `==`.

Also, take John Woo's advice on using `COUNT` or `mysql_num_rows`:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zipcodes FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcodes='$search'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $search = "yes";
}else{
    $search = "no";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The double == always throws me off.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `zipcodes` WHERE` zipcodes = 'value'
```

It will return 0 if the zipcode doesnt exists.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can also do `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (mysql_errno($db_object) == 1062) ? 'duplicate' : 'unique';
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zipcodes FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcodes='$search'");
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zipcodes FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcodes=\"$search\"");
```

the $search variable will not print it value inside single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zipcodes FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcodes='$search'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$search = "yes";
}else{
$search = "no";
}
```